# Papertrail undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, paper-trail-gem

I have this revert method in my controller

```
def revert
  version = PaperTrail::Version.find(params[:id])
  if version.reify
    version.reify(:has_many=>true).save!
  else
    version.item.destroy
  end
  share_type = ShareType.find(params[:share_type_id])
  redirect_to :back
end
```

I am getting error of undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass on

```
version.reify(:has_many=>true).save!
```

but when I try

```
version.reify.save!
```

everything become fine what am I doing wrong I am using revert method for another resource with

```
def revert
  version = PaperTrail::Version.find(params[:id])
  if version.reify
    version.reify(has_many: true).save!
  else
    version.item.destroy
  end
  company = Company.find_by_slug(params[:company_id])
  redirect_to :back
end
```

This works fine with out any error.
here are my models for both resources

```
class ShareType < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_paper_trail
  belongs_to :company 
  has_many :issue_shares, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :shares

  validates :company, :code, :name, :reason, :effective_date, presence: true

  before_save :convert_new_line_to_html

  def convert_new_line_to_html
    self.description.to_s.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "<br>")
  end

end
```

and for company

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged
  has_many :user_companies, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_companies
  has_many :advisor_invitations
  has_many :company_advisors
  has_many :advisors, through: :company_advisors

  belongs_to :created_by, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"

  has_many :share_types, dependent: :destroy
  validates :user_id, :name,:company_no,:company_type,:registered_office, :principle_place, presence: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :company_no

  validates_presence_of :register_address_occupier, :if => lambda { |o| !o.occupied_by_company }
  has_paper_trail

  def slug_candidates
    [
      :name,
      [:name, :company_type],
      [:name, :company_type, :company_no],
   ]
  end
  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
     slug.blank? || name_changed?
  end
  def is_admin?(user)
    !user_companies.where("user_id=? AND role=?",user.id, 0).empty?
  end
  def share_holder?(user)
    shares = Share.includes(issue_share:[:share_type]).where("share_types.company_id=? AND shares.user_id=?", id, user.id).references(:share_types)
    !shares.empty?
  end

  def is_director?(user)
    !user_companies.where("user_id=? AND role=?",user.id, 1).empty?
  end

  def is_advisor?(user)
    !advisors.where("user_id=?",user.id).empty?
  end
end
```

Comment: please always post the whole stacktrace!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem there is an association

```
has_many :users, through: :shares
```

in share_types while I do not have

```
has_many :shares
```

so I need to remove this line

```
has_many :users, through: :shares
```

which I do not need this solved my problem.